# How do I catch and log all attempts to write to /dev/null?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Essentially I'm trying to catch output any scripts that are currently running and silencing their output.

So the question is fairly simple, how do I log any attempts to write to /dev/null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt many folks have done this so far so I guess you will have to live with hints, not facts.

In your shoes, I would go to single user mode (runlevel 1), create a clone node of /dev/null (mknod /dev/nihil c 1 3; chmod 666 /dev/nihil), delete /dev/null, create a fifo called /dev/null and write a script that reads that fifo and writes the log. Then switch back to the usual runlevel.

If you needed the quick (not monitored) /dev/null, you can use /dev/nihil instead while the rest of the system is bigbrothered.

Actually, I would also check the disk of the target log once in a while and stop the logger, delete the fifo and switch back to the original /dev/null node when heavy logging occurs. This kind of rigorous surveillance may turn the system's black hole into its black death.